# Capture dropdown change and update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a gridview in a page and also I have a update button which does bulk update for gridview. I have 5 columns in my gridview out of which first 3 columns are not editable and last two columns have dropdown values.

If I change any one dropdown in a page and click update it saves all the rows of that page. I need to capture only selected row values and update only that row item. Also on top of this how can I capture the old values of that two dropdown and save it in a seperate table which is called the history table. Can anyone advice or suggest me to achieve this?

Comment: Can we have your code and(if possible) a picture of your current project? From here there is some difficulties understanding your problem. After providing us such detail , IT will be easier for us to help you :)

Comment: For history instead of relying on old values of drop downs use triggers on tables.

Comment: Are you setting `SelectedValue` of dropdownlist from db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `HiddenField` for every `DropDownList` cell like,

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hfddl1Val" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("col_name") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
protected void btn_save(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
 foreach(GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
 {
   HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfddl1Val");
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddl1");

   if(hf.Value != ddl.SelectedValue)
   {
      //save
   }
 }
}
```

Then while updating, loop through each row and compare `HiddenField` value (which will be previous data) with `DropDownList` current value (as `ddl1.SelectedValue`). If both are same then no change, otherwise data is changed for that row and you can proceed to save.

Comment: How will the hidden filed capture the old value of the dropdown?

Comment: @Vicky Are you setting `SelectedValue` of `dropdownlist` from db?

Comment: Yes I get values from DB

Comment: @Vicky then assign the same value to `HiddenField`, once you change `DropDownList` value, you still have db value stored in `HiddenField`

Comment: okay, now which ID am I going to give in my hidden field. How can I link this dropdown to the hidden field.

Comment: @Vicky You can use any ID, there is no link with the `DropDownList`, you have 3 dropdowns, use 3 hiddenfields, just remember which hiddenfield stores what data. `HiddenField` is just for storing previous values.

Comment: okay can you pls provide me a sample validation for this in update condition.

Comment: @Vicky I have updated my answer, ask me is anything is not understood.

Comment: ok this is fine and in else condition what can I give for validation.

Comment: @Vicky You want to save only if the `DropDownList` value is changed right? then no need of `else` condition.

Comment: @Vicky Put break point at `if(hf.Value != ddl.SelectedValue)` and check if the control passes `if` condition.

Comment: Yes is passing the if condition but when I select 5 rows and give update I get to see only 4 rows getting updated. And in some cases when I select only row and update I can see 4 rows getting updated.